# Cómo uso grep para filtrar por más de un patrón?

Tags: r, substr

Quiero hacer un filtro de la variable raza de mi df para quedarme solamente con los datos de las razas 911 y 912.

```
ID    |   Peso   |   Raza
-------------------------
001   |   200   |    911 

002   |   450   |    912

003   |   520   |    940 

004   |   300   |    911

005   |   350   |    912

006   |   220   |    985
```

Sé cómo se usa `grep` para filtrar por un patrón, pero para dos o más no lo he conseguido. He intentado

```
filtro<-grep("911, 912", df$Raza)
filtro<-grep("911", "912", df$Raza)
```

Y no me funciona. Seguro que no es tan complicado, pero no he encontrado ningún ejemplo ni la manera de hacerlo. Se me ocurre que también podría hacerlo mediante un `subset` también, pero no lo he intentado antes.

Gracias!

Answer (score 0):

En primer lugar, te comento que no necesitarías usar ninguna búsqueda por medio de expresiones regulares, al menos con el ejemplo que has dado. Veamos:

```
df <- read.table(text="ID    |   Peso   |   Raza
001   |   200   |    911 
002   |   450   |    912
003   |   520   |    940 
004   |   300   |    911
005   |   350   |    912
006   |   220   |    985", header=T, sep='|')

df[df$Raza %in% c(911,912),]

  ID Peso Raza
1  1  200  911
2  2  450  912
4  4  300  911
5  5  350  912
```

Como podrás observar usamos el operador binario `%in%`para filtrar todas las filas dónde `Raza` está incluída en el vector `c(911,912)`.

Para usar `grep()` deberías contar con una columna de tipo caracter, y podrías hacer algo parecido de la siguiente forma:

```
df$RazaString <- as.character(df$Raza)
df[grep('911|912', df$RazaString),]

  ID Peso Raza RazaString
1  1  200  911        911
2  2  450  912        912
4  4  300  911        911
5  5  350  912        912
```

`grep('911|912', df$RazaString)` buscará el patrón `911|912` dónde el `|` hace las veces de u `OR` y retornará las filas dónde se encontró el mismo.

Comment: Muchas gracias Patricio